# What has DiscreteAsymptotic been thinking about for so long?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

The command of 12.2 (This code is related to
[that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144001/general-formula-for-int-01-x-1x-2-dots-x-n-dx#).)

```
DiscreteAsymptotic[RealAbs[Evaluate[Integrate[Product[x - k, {k, 1, n}], {x, 0, 1}, 
Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]]], n -> Infinity]
```

is running on my comp  for hours, producing two warnings in the beginning of its execution.
This is strange in view of the instantly returned input  of the command

```
Integrate[Product[x - k, {k, 1, n}], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

Comment: Look at your integrand: `Product[x - k, {k, 1, n}]` for given x and n->Infinity the integrand alternates the sign and gets larger. This can NOT converge!

Comment: @DanielHuber:  My question is about the asymptotic of the integral, not about the convergence of the product. Did you look at [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144001/general-formula-for-int-01-x-1x-2-dots-x-n-dx#) linked by me?

Comment: With Mathematica 12.3 your "instantly returns" the input slightly altered with `Pochhammer` and also gives an error message about integral "does not converge on {0,1}" and does not evaluate the integral.

Comment: You discovered that Mathematica does not give an asymptotic result.  This is one of many limitations of its capabilities. Now, **what** is your question?

Comment: @Somos: In other words, my question is why doesn't Mathematica return the input in short time here?

Comment: @Somos: You are not right: Version 12.3 on Windows 10 Pro gives few error messages, but continue to run for a long time (I didn't wait any result.).

Comment: @Somos The integral `Integrate[Product[x - k, {k, 1, n}], {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]` converges for each natural`n`.

Answer (score 3):

I am running Mathematica version 12.3.0 for Microsoft Windows.
The code

```
Table[Integrate[Product[x-k, {k, 1, n}], {x, 0, 1}], {n, 8}] //InputForm
```

returns

```
     {-1/2, 5/6, -9/4, 251/30, -475/12, 19087/84, -36799/24, 1070017/90}
```

which is correct. Using PARI/GP returns the same result.

However, the code

```
Timing[Integrate[Product[x - k, {k, 1, n}], {x, 0, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]] // InputForm // Quiet
```

returns

```
{2.234375, Integrate[((-n + x)*Pochhammer[1 - n + x, n])/x, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]}
```

in less than 3 seconds. The `Quiet` suppresses the error message

```
Integrate: integral of ... does not converge on {0,1}.
```

This indicates that while Mathematica can integrate the finite product
for any **specific** positive integer, it is **not** able to do the
integration for a generic positive integer, and furthermore, complains
that the integral does not converge. Of course, this is not true, but
somehow Mathematica gets confused and gets it wrong. The problem seems
to be that

```
Product[x - k, {k, 1, n}] // FullSimplify // InputForm
```

returns

```
Gamma[x]/Gamma[-n + x]
```

and the Gamma function has a pole at $0$ and all negative integers. Thus,
for all $\,x\in(0,1)\,$ and $\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\,$ the quotient of Gammas is
well defined, however, this fails for $\,x=0.\,$ This seems to be what
Mathematica is complaining about, but that is my educated guess. I do not
not have any clear way around this.

Despite this, the MSE question has an answer with the value of the integral as a sum (with a needed `(-1)^k`).

```
a[n_] := Sum[(-1)^k StirlingS1[n, k]/(k + 1), {k, 0, n}];
```

You can test this with the code

```
And @@ Table[a[n] == Integrate[Product[x - k, {k, 1, n}], {x, 0, 1}], {n, 10}]
```

which returns `True`. However, `DiscreteAsymptotic` can't deal with `a[n]`. Still, the asymptotic in the MSE answer is wrong. To a
first approximation, I get the result
$$ (-1)^n I_n \sim n!/\log(n). $$